# Looking for a batch script that will name files in a folder starting with A and going to Z

Tags: batch-file

I have found a bunch of that rename numerically but I need one that will do alphabet. I need the first one to be renamed to just a single A and the last to a Z. I won't have more than 26 files in a folder so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: You seem to have mistaken this site as a code writing service. Have you done any research or made any effort to figure this out yourself first?

Answer (score 1):

This loops through all the files in the directory and renames them to a single alphanumeric character. It may break over 26 files, but I haven't tested that. You also might want to add in your own file extension, but since that wasn't mentioned in the original post, I'll leave that up to you.

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "alpha=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
set /a index=0
for /r %%i in (*) do (ren %%i !alpha:~%index%,1! & set /a index=(%index%+1)%26)
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your input files are named like this

```
apple.txt
banana.txt
cherry.txt
```

Then this untested batch code (please save it in a batch file) should give you

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

Here is the code

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
    set currentFileName=%%a
    REM Remove echo below to rename files
    echo ren %%a !currentFileName:~0,1!%%~xa
)
```